# Creating Dummy Variables from String Column

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, data-science, dummy-variable

I have a pandas dataframe (N = 1485) that looks like this:

```
ID          Intervention
1           Blood Draw, Flushed, Locked
1           Blood Draw, Port De-Accessed, Heparin-Locked, Tubing Changed
1           Blood Draw, Flushed
2           Blood return Verified, Flushed
2           Cap Changed
3           Port De-Accessed
```

I want to be able to dummy code out each of the string before every comma so it looks similar to this:

```
ID          Blood Draw          Flushed          Locked      ....
1              Yes                Yes             Yes
1              Yes                No              No
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: look at `str.get_dummies` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html

Comment: Also search on "one-hot encoding".  Pandas has a one-hot operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and a dictionary mapping:

```
d = {1: 'yes', 0: 'no'}
res = df.join(df.pop('Intervention').str.get_dummies(', ').applymap(d.get))
```

In my opinion, it's best to convert to strings for display purposes only. Boolean values are more efficiently held and manipulated in Boolean series.

**Result**

```
print(res)

   ID Blood Draw Blood return Verified Cap Changed Flushed Heparin-Locked  \
0   1        yes                    no          no     yes             no   
1   1        yes                    no          no      no            yes   
2   1        yes                    no          no     yes             no   
3   2         no                   yes          no     yes             no   
4   2         no                    no         yes      no             no   
5   3         no                    no          no      no             no   

  Locked Port De-Accessed Tubing Changed  
0    yes               no             no  
1     no              yes            yes  
2     no               no             no  
3     no               no             no  
4     no               no             no  
5     no              yes             no
```

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
                   'Intervention': ['Blood Draw, Flushed, Locked',
                                    'Blood Draw, Port De-Accessed, Heparin-Locked, Tubing Changed',
                                    'Blood Draw, Flushed', 'Blood return Verified, Flushed',
                                    'Cap Changed', 'Port De-Accessed']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
for event in ['Blood Draw', 'Flushed', 'Locked']:
    df[event] = df['Intervention'].str.contains(event)
```

which will give you `True`/`False` instead of `'Yes'/'No'` which may be more useful when you are post-processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
df1=df['Intervention'].str.split(',', expand=True)  
df2=df1.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True) # Replacing None with blank data
pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(df2[col]) for col in df2], axis=1, keys=df2.columns)  # Creates dummies for all the columns
```

To perform the above steps, filter the `Intervention` column, do this process and join with original dataframe so that the dummies statement works ( Creates the dummies for all the columns).

Comment: Let me know if this is what you wanted.